# How to stay safe in Mexico City

Tags: safety, mexico, mexico-city

At the end of the month I will be traveling to Mexico City for a weekend. My spanish is okay and I don't really plan on venturing out of the tourist areas. I want to visit Tenochtitlan and some of the museums in the city itself. However, living in Texas all I hear about is how violent and unsafe Mexico is, including the larger cities. I recognize that some of this is likely overblown. Regardless you do hear horrible stories about tourists turning up in shallow graves in the desert. What can I do to make sure my stay is safe and enjoyable?

Comment: The only way to answer this question perfectly is to copy & past [wikivoyag's page](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mexico#Stay_safe) on Mexico... So I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it can be looked up easily in [wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mexico#Stay_safe).

Comment: I wasn't familiar with wikivoyage, thanks for the information

Comment: What is `safe` for you?

Comment: I don't want to be mugged/raped/murdered...

Answer (score 1):

Having been there myself - and visited historical sites and museums - I can tell you that it is quite safe. I had no issues, but obviously you need to be careful ( alert to your surroundings) and apply commonsense (e.g., don't leave your bag unattended and don't display lots of jewellery). I found people there very helpful. The large police presence in the city centre might be intimidating at first, but, you'll actually feel safe in their presence. The only time I felt uneasy was when there were protests - because there was an election coming up.
I really enjoyed my time in Mexico - the museums are absolutely fantastic, and I found the place and its people very endearing.
Have a safe and happy trip!